# how to add new record to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add new records with new indices to a pandas dataframe
for example:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(columns = ['COL1', 'COL2'])
```

Now I have a new record, with index label 'Test1', and values [20, 30]
i would like to do something like (pseudo code):

```
df.append(index='Test1', [20, 30])
```

so my result would be

```
       COL1   COL2
Test1   20     30
```

The furthest i've reached was:

```
df = df.append({'COL1':20, 'COL2':30}, ignore_index=True)
```

but this solution does not includes the new index

Thanks!

Comment: you can try `pd.concat([df,df1])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Citing from the documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated):

> Warning Starting in 0.20.0, the .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor of
>   the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers.

So, you should use loc instead

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['COL1', 'COL2'])
>>> df.loc['test1'] = [20, 30]
>>> df 
      COL1 COL2
test1   20   30
>>> df.shape 
(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 5):

Please note that, as per [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/overview.html#mutability-and-copying-of-data), Series are size-immutable (i.e. appending an entry to a Series will copy the original series and create a new object). This means that appending rows to a DataFrame will keep making unnecessary copies of the entire DataFrame. Highly recommend building a list with your rows, and then making one DataFrame when you have all the rows you need

Answer (score 1):

You can use .ix:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['COL1', 'COL2'])
In [2]: df.ix['test1'] = [20, 30]
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
       COL1  COL2
test1    20    30

[1 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks, but i get KeyError: 'test1', using python 2.7

Comment: @user2476373 it should work if pandas version >= 0.13.1. You can do `pip freeze | grep -i pandas` to check your pandas version and `pip install -U pandas` to update it.